# Trying to setup root homepage using routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set the root path of my domain http://www.example.com/ to the `PersonSearch` controller using the Routing module, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect (404 error).

The URL http://www.example.com/person/search correctly takes me to the desired page.

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Root",
      "",
      defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Search" }
    );
  }
}
```

**PersonController.cs**

```
public class PesonController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("person/search")]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        PersonSearchViewModel psvm = new PersonSearchViewModel();
        return View(psvm);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about switching the route configuration? Set the Root routemap before the attribute based routing.

Comment: You mean just change the order in the code? Move routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); afer the MapRoute() call?

Comment: Yes. And also do what Murilo suggested, it is necessary for MVC to understand the URL construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could achieve what I wanted with a simple Attribute Routing piece of code.

```
public class PesonController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/")]
    [Route("person/search")]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        PersonSearchViewModel psvm = new PersonSearchViewModel();
        return View(psvm);
    }
}
```

I can then remove the call to `routes.MapRoute()` in `RouteConfig`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's missing the url parameter in your route

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Root",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Search" }
    );
```

Comment: the URL I am trying to configure is the root, therefore I left that line blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ordering problem. If you define a URL as empty string (root), the route should be placed *before* all of your other routes.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Search" }
        );

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // Place any other `MapRoute` declarations here
    }
}
```

Comment: The root map works if I comment out routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); but as soon as I add that line back in I get the 404 error for the root (/)

Comment: What happens if you comment the route attribute on Person/Search? If that doesn't help, you might try the divide and conquer approach - comment groups of attribute routes until you find the group the one you are looking for belongs in (when the 404 goes away), then uncomment them one at a time in that group until you find the culprit.

Comment: Did you reverse the order and put `MapRoute` first as I suggested?

Comment: Yes I put `MapRoute()` first and `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` second and that causes the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` to override the `MapRoute()` it seems. The only way I can get the homepage to work is to completely remove `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`