# C# MVC Trying to setup root homepage using routing to override external library root route

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have basically the same issue as:
[Trying to setup root homepage using routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649459/trying-to-setup-root-homepage-using-routing)
and I have tried different variations of MapRoute(), including the namespace approach.

But the solution (using attribute routing `[Route("~/")]` ) is not applicable to me because I have a referenced dll (basically another project holding my login and account controllers) that already have [Route("~/")] in its own dashboard.

When i implement [Route("~/")] in my project's controller as the root route, it is detected as duplicate:
"Multiple controller types were found that match the URL."

I have tried inheriting the parent project's dashboard controller (the one with the `~/`) and not using [Route("~/")] anywhere in mine, but it creates other issues as mismatching the ViewModels used, which I am not allowed to manipulate.

**Is there a way to "hide"/"override"/"ignore" the parent dll's root route from mine and let me use my own action as root?**

I am also trying to avoid using a controller factory as I have several other referenced dlls and it would be foolish to add them all one by one.

**UPDATE:**
Our Global.asax (we have the same, it registers all areas):

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(
                ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().First());

            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

            SiteInitialization.ApplicationStart();
        }
...
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to force the external dashboard into an area within your MVC app? Then its `/` URL would be relative to the URL root associated with that area.

Comment: I am not using any Areas. basically my Global.asax just registers All Areas. Also our Global.asax is basically the same since we are using the same template (called Serene).

Comment: But can you change it to force the external code to register itself in an area?

Comment: um, how do i do that? in the child app?

Comment: trying to apply the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658902/overriding-extending-an-mvc-controller-area but i dont knwo how to convert it to the Root route.